# How to debug error in model / tf.data which works fine in eager mode, but gives an error in keras.fit

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I set a batch of data from tf.data into the model, and the output of the model into my loss function.

Everything works fine, but I still get an error at one of the operations.

How do I go about debugging this? The graph doesn't give specific information on why the code is giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
model.compile(loss=loss_fn,optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5), run_eagerly=True)
```

Which runs the code in eager mode. Most likely, whenever code works in eager mode, but not in graph mode, there is usually an Out of Memory error, particularly for larger computations like matrix multiplication.